# Игнорирование одной из строк при событии onmouseover (JS)

Tags: javascript, mouse-event

Имеется функция, которая меняет цвет строки таблицы при наведении на нее курсора мыши. Предположим, что одна из строк имеет `backgroundColor = "yellow"`(в то время как остальные - белые). Каким образом заставить обработчик `mouseover\mouseout` не совершать событие на "желтой" строке, дабы не перетирать бэкграунд? Спасибо!

```js
function lightingRows() {
  var row = document.getElementsByClassName("row_class");
  [].forEach.call(row, function(row) {
    row.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    });
    row.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Ответ внутри вопроса. Нужно добавить условие `if (this.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") return;` если бэкграунд равен такому-то значению, ничего не делаем.

Comment: добавьте к этой строке какой-нибудь класс, и вообще не вешайте обработчик на эту строку

Comment: бэкграунд тоже проще менять доабвлением класса, тогда при наличии двух классов не менять цвет в css

Comment: да и вообще может через `:hover` решить

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки. Уже немного подустал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто добавить условие проверки на неравенство стиля [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) 
 значению `"yellow"` (как вам написал [@Илья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240582/%D0%98%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F)). Вот так:

```
function lightingRows() {
  var row = document.getElementsByClassName("row_class");
  [].forEach.call(row, function(row) {
    row.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      if (this.style.backgroundColor != "yellow") {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
      }
    });
    row.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      if (this.style.backgroundColor != "yellow") {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: странная какая-то вещь, если вместо `yellow` поставить `#a2dde3` или любой другой неименованный цвет - как-то не хочет отрабатывать...

Comment: @TheHateInMe все правильно, не странно. Ведь сравниваются строки